# How to add a hole to a polygon within a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Tags: r, r-sp

I have a list of polygons in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and need to set one of them as a hole in an other.

I've found in the help of `set_Polypath` how a hole can be defined on a newly created polygon but how to set the "hole" flag on an existing polygon?

Comment: Seems this question has been reposted, with a worked example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629049/how-to-make-holes-to-be-displayed-in-a-spatialpolygons

Comment: @edzer pebesma it is not the same question on is about display, the other about polygons handling in general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have to rebuild the polygon, and then replace it in the spdf.

The following function automatically rebuild the polygon adding a hole:

```
library("sp")
AddHoleToPolygon <-function(poly,hole){
    # invert the coordinates for Polygons to flag it as a hole
    coordsHole <-  hole@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords
    newHole <- Polygon(coordsHole,hole=TRUE)

    # punch the hole in the main poly
    listPol <- poly@polygons[[1]]@Polygons
    listPol[[length(listPol)+1]] <- newHole
    punch <- Polygons(listPol,poly@polygons[[1]]@ID)

    # make the polygon a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame as the entry
    new <- SpatialPolygons(list(punch),proj4string=poly@proj4string)
    new <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(new,data=as(poly,"data.frame"))

    return(new)
}
```

You can then then define a polygon with a whole from two polygons in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame:

```
load(url("http://spatcontrol.net/CorentinMBarbu/misc/spdf.rda"))
punchedPoly <-AddHoleToPolygon(spdf[1,],spdf[2,])
```

And get:
[image: visualize punched polygon]

And then replace the polygon in the spdf

```
spdf <- rbind(punchedPoly,spdf[2,])
plot(spdf,col=c(1,2),main="New SpatialPolygonsDataFrames")
```

[image]

Comment: what structure have poly and hole for the function to run? I just have the coordinates of the both polygons

Comment: @cmbarbu Yours function helped me a lot! I could not do this operation by any packages I found on CRAN. Than you!